# Number of retransmitted Wifi packets in C++ under Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wifi, wlanapi

I need to get the number (and size in bytes) of retransmitted Wifi packets with C++ under Windows. The Information I need is very low-level, encapsulated in the Frame Control of Wifi-Frame.

- Is there an interface to get the information I need directly from Windows/WinApi?

I got two attempts to achieve the information I want, but there are also questions:

1. **Native WiFi API:** has a struct called `WLAN_STATISTICS` which contains an array of structs [WLAN_PHY_FRAME_STATISTICS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706914(v=vs.85).aspx) with the field `ullRetryCount`.

   - Why is the `WLAN_PHY_FRAME_STATISTICS` an array? What does the elements represent?
   - Is the `ullRetryCount` the information I need? I get values here, but I can't be certain it's correct...
2. **IP Helper API**: with the the struct `MIB_IF_ROW2` there is the field `OutDiscards`, where I don't get any values. Maybe my connection is to good and no frames are discarded?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you won't get this information, unless you have a specialized driver. Or, set up a sniffer, capture all communication from this device and find retransmissions.

WLAN_STATISTICS is an array because it can have several instances on devices with multiple PHYs. One WLAN_PHY_FRAME_STATISTICS table per PHY.

Discards on IP level are usually caused by "Quality of service" shaping, it is much higher layer than wifi phy.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Yes a possibility is to program my own sniffer routine, but i cant find another proper API except WinPcap. The Problem is I cant see the WIFI-header because WinPcap transform Wifi-Headers to Fake-Ethernet-Headers without RetryFlag.......  What does multiple PHYs mean? I get an array with size 4 and I can get values from nearly every element in this array, but where do i know which is the right one?  The documentation is very thin. ......... I thought the MIB_IF_ROW2 Structure shows an lower layer because of the fields octets field

Comment: Multiple PHYs mean two and more. For example one 5ghz another 2.5 GHz.

Comment: So every entry in the PHY-array is related to one WLAN-Phy-Mode for example a/b/g/n? Is there a way to figure out, which index in the PHY-array belongs to which PHY?

Comment: I've seen recently new higher-end routers that have two 5 Ghz PHYs, one for serving as AP and another for WiFi Direct mode or bridging independently. The API should allow querying of Phy details.